# Is it necessary to have a TimeMachine backup of the Backblaze Directory?

Tags: backup, time-machine

Since I noticed TimeMachine continuously backing up large files, I had a look with `tmutil compare` to see where those files are located. Since I had not worked on my mac book air but used it to listen to music I suspected the iTunes library.

As it turns out TimeMachine is continuously backing up `/Library/Backblaze.bzpkg/`.

Do I really need a backup of this directory? I see the point that in case I have a hardware failure but my TimeMachine is still working I might need to re-upload everything to Backblaze again?

What would be arguments against putting `/Library/Backblaze.bzpkg/` into the excluded items list of Time Machine?

Answer (score 4):

This file is where Backblaze stores information about what is stored on their servers and copies of files being uploaded or about to be uploaded. I would exclude this from Time Machine backups, as it will often change and contains nothing you're not already backing up elsewhere.

Comment: I think this is correct but is there any documentation showing this?